# is it safe to call delete inside a remove_if predicate?

Tags: c++, iterator

I have a vector

```cpp
std::vector<Object*> objects;
```

And a method that removes an object if it's found:

```cpp
void Remove(Object *o)
{
    objects.erase(
        std::remove_if(
            objects.begin(), objects.end(),
            [&o](Object *_object) {
                if (o == _object)
                {
                    delete _object;
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        ),
        objects.end()
    );
}
```

Is this safe? Should I not call `delete`? But then would `erase` call `delete` for me? I'm a bit confused. Would this invalidate the iterator or leak memory?

Comment: Your lambda `delete`s every object, whether it's a match or not.

Comment: You're probably better served using `unique_ptr` (or `shared_ptr`) and not thinking about `new`/`delete`.

Comment: @DrewDormann sorry about that, I meant it like this.

Comment: This seems like a lot of (fragile) work to emulate what `std::unique_ptr` would have done for you automatically.

Comment: @DrewDormann I know and understand that, but I do want to know how it would work.

Comment: @user17732522 This is not possible when polymorphism is required, due to object slicing. That's why tools like `std::unique_ptr` exist.

Comment: In that case, you might want to clarify what you mean by "correct".  Are you asking if it compiles?  Is well-defined?  Bug-prone?  Viewed as good practice?  Terse?

Comment: @DrewDormann I'm asking if it's safe. Would this leak memory or invalidate the iterator?

Comment: It is not possible to determine whether it's "safe" to call `delete` here. An authoritative answer requires knowing the exact rules for when all of these objects get `new`ed in the entire program, and when, exactly, they must be `delete`d. The shown `delete` may be safe. Or it may not be. Without a [mre] nobody will be able to answer this. C++ is just too complicated, for an absolute answer like that.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik That is the entire program. I just wanted to know if it would be safe by itself. Or if I shouldn't be calling `delete`.

Comment: No, this is clearly not the "entire program". No self-respecting C++ compiler would produce a runnable program from the shown code. It would be quite an amazing achievement, given the fact that it lacks a `main`, and the actual declaration of what the mysterious `Object` is all about is also missing; also, earlier comments suggested that the shown code was manually edited, by hand, so at best the accuracy of the transcription is suspect, at worse the shown code is not real code but fake code, and the real code does not really contain anything named `Object`, for example...

Comment: The `erase` algorithm will not call `delete` for you, and it is perfectly safe to allow it to move `delete`d pointers around. The algorithm doesn't care that your type is a pointer type, and doesn't attempt to dereference those pointers. `delete` only affects the *pointed-at memory*, not the pointer itself. A pointer is *just a numeric value used for addressing*, and doesn't have uninitialized, deleted etc. states. You don't get to find out until you attempt to dereference them.

Comment: What container is owning the objects pointed out in that `std::vector<Object*> objects;`?

Comment: "safe" is as vague a term as "correct" here.  What you are showing here does not show any apparent memory leaks, but if I were reviewing this code, I would say "Rewrite all of this, because it invites bugs.  And I don't view code that invites bugs to be _safe_".  That's using my definition of "safe", however.  Your definition of "safe" may differ.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @JaackoTorus If you need a base class pointer in your `vector` but "_want to know how it would work_" without a `unique_ptr`, I suggest that you implement something very _similar_ to `unique_ptr`. The smallest pointer-owning wrapper you can think of that just owns the pointer and exposes it via certain operator overload and member functions would do fine here. Just read up on "_the rule of 3/5/0_". With such a class, you could let the object with the `vector` be destroyed without implementing a user defined destructor in that class.

Comment: If `o` may appear in `objects` more than once, then this code exhibits undefined behavior by way of double deletion. If it's guaranteed to appear at most once, then I believe this code is well defined (though somewhat fragile and not necessarily a good idea). This function is going to be very difficult and error-prone to use - when it returns, the caller has no way to know whether the pointer they passed to it is still valid or already dangling.

Comment: @JaackoTorus You're welcome! It's a more "nip it in the bud" kind of solution. Make a class that owns a resource and make it good. That way you can use and reuse it within most containers (like `vector`s) and don't have to bother about deleting etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Would this invalidate the iterator or leak memory?

Memory doesn't get leaked by individual bits of code; it gets leaked by complete programs. *Someone* has to be responsible for deallocation, but just because it doesn't happen here, doesn't mean it won't happen at all. *Not* calling `delete` here would *also* not "leak memory"; what leaks memory is the *entire program*. Code like this cannot stand on its own.

It's difficult to figure out where the responsibility lies, except by following established patterns. That's why tools like `std::unique_ptr<T>`, `std::shared_ptr<T>` and `std::weak_ptr<T>` exist. Please use them.

The iterator will not be invalidated. The iterator is iterating over elements of the container, which are the pointers themselves. `delete` does not affect the pointers it's used with. `delete` affects the pointed-at memory.

> Would `erase` call `delete` for me?

No.

> Is this safe?

Code like this risks a double deallocation (**undefined behaviour**) if *any* other code *could possibly* attempt to `delete` *any* of the same pointed-at elements from the container.

Again, this is not a local risk, it is a whole-program risk.

Again, figuring out memory management across a whole-program context is difficult in general. Please use standard library tools like `std::unique_ptr<T>`, `std::shared_ptr<T>` and `std::weak_ptr<T>`, as appropriate to the situation, in appropriate ways. A proper tutorial on memory management in C++ is beyond the scope of a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: "Memory doesn't get leaked by individual bits of code; it gets leaked by complete programs." However, it can often be shown that a particular bit of code loses the last pointer or reference by which a dynamically allocated object could be reached, whereupon the leak is inevitable. It is then reasonable to say that this bit of code is responsible for the leak.

Comment: Yes, sometimes it is clear who's responsible. In those cases, it's easy to choose the standard library tool for the job. Otherwise it's harder, but still a much better idea than trying to express that policy manually.

Answer (score 1):

From [`std::remove_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove)

> UnaryPredicate must meet the requirements of [Predicate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Predicate).

and from there:

> The function object `pred` shall not apply any non-constant function through the dereferenced iterator. This function object may be a pointer to function or an object of a type with an appropriate function call operator.

(It should be possible to call the predicate twice on same element).

Your predicate doesn't respect that requirement, so code is **unsafe**.

Keeping your logic, you might use [`std::partition`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition):

```
void Remove(/*const*/ Object *o)
{
    auto it = std::partition(objects.begin(), objects.end(),
                             [&o](const Object* object) { return o != object; }
                            );
    for (auto it2 = it; it2 != objects.end(); ++it2) { delete *it2; }
    objects.erase(it, objects.end());
}
```

but using smart pointers (as [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) (so `objects` would be `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Object>>` instead of `std::vector<Object*>`)) would simplify the code:

```
void Remove(/*const*/ Object *o)
{
    objects.erase(
        std::remove_if(
            objects.begin(), objects.end(),
            [&o](const std::unique_ptr<Object>& object) {
                return o != object.get();
            }
        ),
        objects.end()
    );
}
```

Comment: So by saying use `std::unique_ptr`, everyone else was saying to use it *inside* the lambda! I assumed they meant to replace everything with smart pointers, which is not what I had in mind. I now understand.

Comment: I pretty sure every comments about smart pointer was for the content of the container, even if not clear enough it seems.